# Should you write $i = \sqrt{-1}$ or $i := \sqrt{-1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, notation

Is one of the following more correct than the other, or does it simply not matter?

$i = \sqrt{-1} \quad$ or $\quad i := \sqrt{-1}$?

Here I am using $:=$ to mean "defined to be equal to."

Comment: I wouldn’t write either.

Comment: @Randall okay, what could you write instead?

Comment: @Randall Do you mind expanding on this comment? Otherwise is not very useful for the OP

Comment: $i^2=-1$........

Comment: @caverac   You are correct.  Fair point.

Comment: @Randall Understood, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of them are correct as the square root is not a single-valued function. The best expression (i.e. simplest) defining $i$ would be $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Okay fair enough. Why not $i^2 := -1$?

Comment: Okay, I think the OP had an error. Let's think about $i$ as $\pm\sqrt{-1}$. $i=\pm\sqrt{-1}$ or $i:=\pm\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: You can write that. $:=$ is usually used in definitions. Since $i$ is widely used, we don't need to "define" it everytime. Also, that notation is hardly ever used. But if you want, no one is stopping you (possibly once in a discussion/problem).

Comment: @manooooh Okay, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @SinTan1729 Okay, thank  you for the clarification.

Comment: You're most welcome.